# Storing user specific data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my application each user has it's own menus depending on changing information on the database.

This way when a user logs-in I have to keep the parameters he can choose somewhere in a Station state table.

So when he choose the parameters I'll retrieve the correspondent option id and make a response from there.

I'm keeping this value in a Current Session object but I'm encountering several problems.

What's the best practice for doing this? 
I'm reading several articles that state the Session object is not a good idea in `ASP.NET MVC`.

Answer (score 1):

Session objects can still be used within MVC check out the answer here [Using Session objects in MVC, Is it really bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878252/using-session-objects-in-mvc-is-it-really-bad)

It points to 2 other questions that had a similar question.

What kind of problems are you having?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Asp.Net Cookies, you can create, assign and destroy within the controller
Follow this link [Cookies in ASP.Net MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803179/cookies-in-asp-net-mvc-5) for more help ...