# Cookies in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing an application in which users are SignUp or SignIn by External Identity Providers like AAD, Google, WS-Federated Authentication etc. Now I want to create cookies on a user machine to logged in until user SignOut. Give me some thought and guide me how I can overcome it. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use **Request.Cookies** and **Response.Cookies** to handle your situation. once user coming back from third party authorization create cookie and store it in browser and once user Logout clear the cookie.

```
 string cookievalue ;
 if ( Request.Cookies["cookie"] != null )
 {
    cookievalue = Request.Cookies["cookie"].Value.ToString();
 }
 else
 {
    Response.Cookies["cookie"].Value = "cookie value";
 }
```

For removing cookie use following code

```
if (Request.Cookies["cookie"] != null)
{
    Response.Cookies["cookie"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);   
}
```

Comment: Then how to use this code ?

 ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("aa") {  Expires = new DateTime().AddDays(5) , HttpOnly = true, Value = "val" });